# No-Model Formtastic Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I am looking to reproduce the following with [Formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic):

```
<% form_tag '/search', :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
<% end %>
```

So far I have:

```
<% semantic_form_for :search, :html => { :method => :get } do |form| %>
  <% form.inputs do %>
    <%= form.input :q %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, this requires access to the parameter hash using:

```
params[:search][:q]
```

Instead of my required:

```
params[:q]
```

I'd like to use Formtastic for all forms in the application I am working on, and so far I have only had problems with this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<%= form.input :q, :input_html => { :name => 'q' } %>`

Answer (score 5):

Formtastic's semantic_form_for is wrapped around Rails' form_for, which only allows "model" forms like the one you're describing. I'm pretty sure you mean "desired" rather than "required", because it's pretty easy to access params[:search][:q] or duplicate the value to params[:q] yourself.

Comment: Hi Justin. It is indeed a 'desired' request. I do have a mobile client interface that posts to the same route using params[:q], however I can add a hack around. Also, thanks for creating Formastic! The GEM is amazing!

Answer (score 4):

http://affy.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-formtasic-without-activerecord.html

Comment: Don't use a link to an external source without providing answer inline. Link not always would be accessible.